# How do I implement different task scheduling algorithms in Linux

Tags: server, scheduler, ubuntu-18.04, process-management

A few colleagues and I are currently sharing a server to run simulations. We were hoping to implement a priority-based scheduling algorithm on the server so that more pressing jobs are run first.

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04 and if I am not mistaken it is currently running the default CFS.

I haven't attempted to install anything or play around with the current scheduler. I'd rather not make any dramatic mistakes and mess it up.

Any assistance or resources that could help implement a process scheduling solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: An open-source software that can be used to do this:
https://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can using cronjob to scheduling in linux

Comment: we were thinking of looking into using slurm after all